# Using HTML5/CSS3 to perform image animation the old-fashioned way (That means Sprite animation!)

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm attempting to use a sprite sheet to perform animation.  I've spurned canvas and gone down the HTML5/CSS3 route of displaying images to the screen but have run into a potential stumbling block before even beginning.

Here's a sample sprite sheet (excuse the horrific programmer-art):

http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/9126/stickmanrun.jpg

So frame 1 is (<0,0><64,64>), frame 2 is (<64,0><128,64>) etc.

In order to render my images I'm grabbing a  and then inserting innerHTML in order to represent my images, for example (in pseudo-code):

```
var image = document.createElement('image.jpg');
var render = get <div id='RenderSpace'>

render.innerHTML = <div xpos ypos framexy1(e.g 0,0) image>
```

My problem is how do I specify the region of the image I want to 'clip' out?

Surely this must be straight-forward but I've only found information using a clip mask which isn't really want I want, I just want to specify a RECT that 'cuts-out' the image from the sprite sheet and I then want to specify a RECT which describes where I want to 'paste' it on to the screen.

Comment: Never thought I would see HTML5, CSS3 and "old-fashioned" in the same sentence.

Comment: Yes it sounds counter intuitive but surely what I'm trying to do is straight-forward and saves me having to load an incredible number of animation frames at entry.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "Sprite based animation"

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Splicing a single rectangular clip out of an image to present it in an HTML element? Do you want to use JavaScript? Are you using `canvas`?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is lazy... Every 250m/s the function will run and increment the "animStep" variable...

You can then relate this to the `background-position` of you element...

See here for example (using jQuery): http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/mjxQW/

```
var animStep = 0;
var bgX = 0;

function checkAnimStep() {

    //UPDATE THE BACKGROUND-POSITION HERE

    //*********

    switch(animStep) {
        case 0:
            bgX = 64;
            animStep++;
            break;
        case 1:
            bgX = 128;
            animStep = 0;
            break;
        case 2:
            bgX = 128;
            animStep++;
            break;
        case 3:
            bgX = 256;
            animStep++;
            break;
        case 4:
            bgX = 128;
            animStep++;
            break;
        case 5:
            bgX = 64;
            animStep = 0;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(checkAnimStep, 250);
});
```

​

Comment: Ok, there are LOADS of ways this could of been done more efficiently - but until `OP` gives us more information, I won't elaborate ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply (and taking the time to have a fiddle, a picture - or bit of code - speaks a thousand words!)

Answer (score 0):

One way to clip an image in HTML/CSS it to set it as a background of a div, specifying the size of the div and the position of the background, something like this.

In HTML:

```
<div id="frame">&nbsp;</div>
```

In CSS:

```
#id {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-image: url(/image.jpg);
}
```

And then in javascript, to set a particular frame:

```
function setFrame(idx) {
    var posx = -64 * idx;
    document.getElementById('frame').style.backgroundPosition = (posx + "px 0px");
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, the backgroundPosition was what I was after!